# Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element error in react-router 2 dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-router-component

I have simple Hello World App with one route no child route or index route. For routing i using [plain routes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes) instead of jsx sysntax. Again i am using react-router's [dynamic routing](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md) to load Hello component with webpack.
My **app.jsx file has the following code**.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router, browserHistory} from "react-router";
import Hello from "./components/Hello";



const routes = [{
    path:"/",
    getComponents(location, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
            callback(null, require('./components/Hello'))
        })
    }
}];


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}  routes={routes}/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

**Hello.jsx component has the following code**

```
import React from "react";
export default class Hello extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error happens because webpack doesn't support es6 modules

if you are using babel to transpile es6 code then use the default keyword like

```
require('./components/Hello').default
```

so the routes will be

```
const routes = [{
    path:"/",
    getComponents(location, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
            callback(null, require('./components/Hello').default)
        })
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. Save a day