# Split component wasn't rendered after getComponent()

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I used Code Splitting for React Router to load component async, and I made it successfully. But when i opened my page in browser, i got nothing. Here're some key code snippets:

### routeConfig

```
// When i removed the annotation below, it did render !
// import Home from './containers/Home/Home'

const routeConfig = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    //indexRoute: {
    //    component: Home
    //}
    getIndexRoute(location, callback) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            callback(null, require('./containers/Home/Home'))
        }, 'Home');
    }
}];
```

### Home.jsx

```
console.log('HOME'); // It works!
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log('HOME COMPONENT'); // not working!
    }   
}
```

Any ideas? I'm stuck here :(

---

Here're my full webpack config codes:

```
/**
 * webpack config
 */
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'react-dom',
            'redux',
            'react-redux',
            'react-router',
            'redux-logger',
            'redux-thunk'
        ],
        main: [
            './html/index'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        // path: path.join(__dirname, 'html/dist'),
        path: './html/dist',
        publicPath: '/html/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread'],
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "style!css!less"
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable
        // 'react': 'React',
        // 'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        // 'redux': 'Redux',
        // 'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
        // 'react-router': 'ReactRouter',
        // 'redux-logger': 'reduxLogger',
        // 'redux-thunk': 'ReduxThunk'
    },
    // add this handful of plugins that optimize the build
    // when we're in production
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ] : [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'vendor'
        })
    ]
};
```

Hope this would help.

Home.js did being loaded, but the Home component seems to be uninitialized.

Comment: How do you export Home? did you write `default export class Home extends Component`?

Comment: @DamienLeroux Yes, i did, pretty sure.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your config, maybe there is a setting causing webpack to not resolve the loaders correctly.

Comment: @SeanLarkin Done, check it out thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Refer to links below:

[invariant-violation-the-root-route-must-render-a-single-element-error-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194806/invariant-violation-the-root-route-must-render-a-single-element-error-in-react)

[react-router/issues/2588](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2588)

[react-router/issues/2881](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2881)